# outdated zmq pkg w/ CVE in bionic updates

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, security

both bionic and bionic-updates contain:

libzmq5 (4.2.5-1ubuntu0.2) [universe]
    lightweight messaging kernel (shared library)

which has been compromised w/ 9.0 level CVE exploit here:
https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2019-6250/

Since Bionic is an LTS, shouldn't this be updated to 4.3.1? It's fixed in disco (19.04+)

cheers

Answer (score 0):

ZeroMQ is in universe, which means it is community supported.

If you are able, I suggest coordinating with upstream and posting a debdiff for this issue. When a debdiff is available, members of the security team will review it and publish the package. See the following link for more information: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/UpdateProcedures